# Is there any way to draw a line diagram using array of x, y co-ordinates in appcelerator?

Tags: line, appcelerator, diagram

If I select one of these co-ordinates, I want to highlight that point on the diagram (by a circle or whatever shape possible). Also I would like to save it later on.

I'm not sure if Appcelerator is flexible enough to do all these things (My search didn't yield much apart from [here](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/5941#!overview), this only supports Android), If not I'll have to generate this diagram in my webservice and pull it back on UI once there is an update in the co-ordinate array.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Chartist](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/) inside a webview and it worked great. It produces a SVG graph instead of a canvas object which performs better.

If you want to use hyperloop you can use [Ti.AndroidCharts](https://loopmodules.com/downloads/ti-androidcharts/)